# Substring using Oracle SQL regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I've created a regex which would capture the string I need. 
When I am testing regex on websites such as [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) then everything works, however when I put the same regex into `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function then it doesn't work.

Here are 2 SQL examples (one with text in English and another one in Kristaps Porzingis' language):

```
SELECT regexp_substr('<ul data-error-code="REOPENED" data-unique-error-code="REOPENED"><li class="b">This is the text I would like to substr! <p class="tutorial" href="#">Other random text that I do not need</li></ul>'
                    ,'<li class="b">([\wāēīšžģņļčķū:!,\b\s]+)<') 
  FROM dual;

SELECT regexp_substr('<ul data-error-code="REOPENED" data-unique-error-code="REOPENED"><li class="b">Šī ir valoda, ko lielākā daļa no jums nesaprot! <p class="tutorial" href="#">Other random text that I do not need</li></ul>'
                    ,'<li class="b">([\wāēīšžģņļčķū:!,\b\s]+)<') 
  FROM dual;
```

I am trying to select text between `<li class="b">` and next html tag, which in this case is `<p class="tutorial">`.

Any advice on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML with regex is not advisable, you'd better fetch the strings and parse them with a language that has convenient means to parse HTML.

If you only have Oracle DBMS at hand, for a one-off job, you may consider using the following `regexp_substr`:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('<ul><li class="b">Šī ir valoda, ko lielākā daļa no jums nesaprot! <p>Not needed</li></ul>',
      '<li\s+class="b">([^<]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as RESULT from dual
```

See the [REXTESTER demo](http://rextester.com/HOY67205):

[image]

Here,

- `<li\s+class="b">` - matches `<li`, 1+ whitespaces, `class="b">`literal substring
- `([^<]+)` - *captures* into Group #1 one or more chars other than `<`

The last `1` argument lets you access the contents of this Group 1.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, for this job I have only Oracle DBMS. I completely agree with you that parsing HTML with regex must be done in other, more appropriate languages.

Comment: @Alex FYI, depending on the version, the Oracle DBMS has build in methods to work with XML. For example [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions051.htm) which allows you to use an xpath. But yeah, HTML isn't exactly XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify that regex.
Instead of looking for specific characters, look for characters that are not `<` or `>`

For example:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('<ul><li class="b">Šī ir valoda, ko lielākā daļa no jums nesaprot! <p>Not needed</li></ul>'
                    ,'<li class="b">([^<>]+)',1,1,'i',1) as b_class
FROM dual
```

Where `[^<>]` matches any character that's not `<` or `>`

Or you could lazy match the characters till the first `<`

```
SELECT regexp_substr('<ul><li class="b">Šī ir valoda, ko lielākā daļa no jums nesaprot! <p>Not needed</li></ul>'
                    ,'<li class="b">(.*?)<',1,1,'ni',1) as b_class
FROM dual
```

The `.*?` will try to consume characters till the first `<`
And by adding the [match parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) `n` it'll also match if there's a multiline text after the tag.

> 'n' allows the period (.), which is the match-any-character character,
>   to match the newline character. If you omit this parameter, the period
>   does not match the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Instr to search for the position of the first html tag and do a substring after that position to get the tail of the text. The next step is to search for '<' on this tail and to use substring again.

Something like

```
select substring(mytext, 1, instr(mytext, '<')) from 
(
 select substring(text, instr(text, '<li class="b">') + 
 length('<li class="b">') +1) as mytext from table
)
```